# How to get user's computer local timezone with offset in Perl?

Tags: perl, timezone, offset

I am trying to get user's computer local timezone with offset in Perl using below code:

```
use POSIX;
my $timezone = strftime("%z", localtime());
print "\n==Time zone offsets===".$timezone."\n";
```

The above script print output like below when run script on local computer:

```
==Time zone offsets===+0530
```

When run same script from live server but on same computer, it displaying different output like below:

```
==Time zone offsets===-0400
```

I want script should always return timezone offset of user's local computer instead of server.

Please help I am trying but not getting it.

Comment: Where in the world is your live server, and where are you? It sounds like one or the other of your systems is wrongly configured, but a discrepancy of 9.5 hours is enormous! There is no way for most PCs to know where they are unless the system operator tells them!

Comment: Currently I am in India but server in USA

Comment: So the numbers are correct. You will have to pass your local time zone to the server to make the necessary adjustments.

Comment: Thanks! Can you help me please  to pass local time zone to server using script get it correctly?

Comment: How does user connect to server?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide the user's time zone. That is done as follows using [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime):

```
$ for tz in local Asia/Calcutta; do
     perl -e'
        use feature qw( say );
        use DateTime qw( );
        say DateTime->now( time_zone => $ARGV[0] );
     ' "$tz"
  done
2016-08-10T13:20:06
2016-08-10T22:50:06
```

You could also set the `TZ` env var appropriately.

```
$ export TZ
$ for TZ in America/Toronto Asia/Calcutta; do
     perl -e'
        use feature qw( say );
        use DateTime qw( );
        say DateTime->now( time_zone => "local" );
     '
  done
2016-08-10T13:20:06
2016-08-10T22:50:06
```

`TZ` also affects `localtime`.

```
$ export TZ
$ for TZ in America/Toronto Asia/Calcutta; do
     perl -e'
        use feature qw( say );
        use POSIX qw( strftime );
        say strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", localtime);
     '
  done
2016-08-10T13:20:06
2016-08-10T22:50:06
```

If you change `$ENV{TZ}` within your script, you need to call `POSIX::tzset();` afterwards.

```
$ perl -e'
     use feature qw( say );
     use POSIX qw( strftime tzset );
     for my $tz (qw( America/Toronto Asia/Calcutta )) {
        $ENV{TZ} = $tz;
        tzset();
        say strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", localtime);
     }
  '
2016-08-10T13:20:06
2016-08-10T22:50:06
```